# Can javascript decrease an html value when it's already going up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I can't find a way for when the value is over 180 (using an if statement), it starts going down as a negative, for example: when the value is over 180, the element with the id "text" becomes -179 then as the slider goes farther, it becomes up to -1.
Here is my code;

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

slider.addEventListener('input', () => {

  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = slider.value;
  document.getElementById("outer").style.transform = `rotate(${slider.value}deg)`;
  var tv = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
  if (slider.value > 180) {
    neg();
  }; //else when it goes back
  function neg() { //stack overflow how to
    document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = Math.floor(-slider.value + 360 / 2);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#outer {
  background: red;
  height: 20vw;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#inner {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateY(10%);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: darkgreen;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50%;
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 3ch;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
<input class="item" value="0" min="0" max="360" type="range" id="slider">
<div id="text" class="item" style="background-color:lightgrey;padding-inline:1vw;border-radius:10%;border:1vh solid black;">
  0
</div>
```

Right now, it resets at -0 instead of -179.
Sorry if the code is messy, because I have been experimenting to figure this out.

Comment: If the slider value is a little over 180, say 180.1, then the neg method resets it to floor(-180.1 + 180), which is floor(-0.1), which is 0.  Why are you subtracting 180?

Comment: Try a max value of 359 on the slider, and not 360.

Comment: Another way is to put the range between `min` -180 and `max` 180. Would make more sense as well when looking at UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for:

```
if (slider.value > 180) {
    document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = slider.value - 360;
  };
```

After slider.value is > 180, the display value switches to slider.value - 360.

```
slider.value = 181 then display value is 181 - 360 = -179
slider.value = 182 then display value is 182 - 360 = -178
slider.value = 183 then display value is 183 - 360 = -177
...
```

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

slider.addEventListener('input', () => {

  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = slider.value;
  document.getElementById("outer").style.transform = `rotate(${slider.value}deg)`;
  var tv = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
  if (slider.value > 180) {
    document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = slider.value - 360;
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#outer {
  background: red;
  height: 20vw;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#inner {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateY(10%);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: darkgreen;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50%;
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 3ch;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
<input class="item" value="0" min="0" max="360" type="range" id="slider">
<div id="text" class="item" style="background-color:lightgrey;padding-inline:1vw;border-radius:10%;border:1vh solid black;">
  0</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks so simple, I couldn't have found it myself. But is all you changed "- 360"?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I removed the neg() function as well.